# Install DJI Onboard SDK on ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS without apt-get

Tags: apt, 16.04

I'm still not that expert with Ubuntu and I'm currently trying to install DJI onboard SDK package for ROS kinetic which is a beta version for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS so it doesn't support `apt-get`,  I'll try to install it using `sudo dpkg -i`. My question is, is it a must to have .deb file in the package so I can use this command or there are other extensions?

The package is compatible with Ubuntu 14, but I don't want to change my OS at the moment.

Comment: You mean something like `sudo dpkg -i some-package.deb`?

Comment: that's true..sorry for confusion

Comment: Can you give the name of the package?

Comment: @Anwar it's dji onboard sdk
it's a drone simulator.

Comment: @MinaBenyamin first, always try to give as much information as you can. Otherwise your question will be closed misinterpreted wrongly. secondly, Just ask plain question with the problem, not about a possible solution you thought might work. For example, You'll ask "How do i install dji onboard sdk in Ubuntu".

Answer (score 0):

If you do trust the source of the package I recommend downloading the installer scripts from their official website and running them. The fact is that the developers provide the latest version of the required package which may or may not be available from `apt-get` repositories.